# How can I remove the "Deleted Items", "Applications" entries from the netbook launcher?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, unity, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete Apps and Files & Folder (lenses) icons from Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42340/how-to-delete-apps-and-files-folder-lenses-icons-from-launcher)

Is it possible to remove the "Deleted Items", "Applications" and/or "Files & Folders" entries on the unity dock (ubuntu 10.10 sidebar) if they are not needed? Repeating what is done for removing other launcher entries does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a way to remove the Deleted Items (the trash can looking thing).

However removing the following two packages will remove the Applications and Files and Folders: `sudo apt-get remove unity-place-applications unity-place-files`

You will need to log out and back in for that to take effect.

Comment: Doing this messed up the Dash and Alt+F2 for me. Instead, run the command `sudo gedit /usr/share/unity/places/*.place` and edit the two files that open as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1734534).