# How to delete Apps and Files & Folder (lenses) icons from Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, lenses

[image: Apps and Files & Folders icons in Launcher]

Hi there, I've been looking for some information about how to delete those Icons (Applications and Files & Folders).

Why? Simple, because I understand that Ubuntu's button (BFB) it's a better solution, I can reach to the same options and I understand that there is not any good reason for have 3 different buttons for the same target.

From BFB I can find apps, files, folders.

Deleting those items (I've proposed into Ayatana) we recover more space, good space.

So, do you know how to delete theme, or just hide them?

Thanks!

Martín.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run the command `gksu gedit /usr/share/unity/places/applications.place` and add `ShowEntry=false` line below `Shortcut=a` and below `ShowGlobal=false` for removing the application lens.

Run the command `gksu gedit /usr/share/unity/places/files.place` and add `ShowEntry=false` line below `Shortcut=f` for removing the fie lens.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1734534).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Wile I was answering other comments I've saw yours. Deleting those files we lose the functions and that's not the idea. Thanks!