# Removing 'Applications' from Unity launcher while still accessing it using shortcut

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcut-keys

Is it possible to remove/hide 'Applications' from launcher, but I still want to access it using shortcut keys (Super+a),  I know the method to [remove the lenses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42340/how-to-delete-apps-and-files-folder-lenses-icons-from-launcher), but I would like to keep them installed, just not show the icon on the launcher.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: This is not the exact duplicate! I know the method to remove launcher items (like Applications, etc.) from launcher. What I asked was I still want to access such items using keyboard shortcuts but I don't want them in my launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible with Unity in 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies as "shortcut keys," but if you want, you can hit Super (or whatever brings up that unity box, as per your settings), and navigate to it with the arrow keys. It's not one key combo, but it is a keyboard-based solution, and you can probably get used to doing it pretty fast.

Sadly, though, I'm pretty sure it's impossible to remove "Applications" in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First, the question you referenced has been updated and now shows how to remove the `Applications` icon from the launcher. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42340/how-to-delete-apps-and-files-folder-lenses-icons-from-launcher/42348#42348).

Another thing you might be interested in: if you install CompizConfig Settings Manager (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`), under the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin", you can set the Launcher to never show. The shortcut keys will still do what they're supposed to, though. (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will still open the first application on the launcher.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [devilspie [image: Install devilspie]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/devilspie).
2. Create a configuration directory for devilspie: `mkdir ~/.devilspie`
3. Create a configuration file like this:

   > ```
   > (if
   >   (is (application_name) "Thunderbird")
   >   (skip_tasklist)
   > )
   > ```

   To find out the exact application name, execute `xprop | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)` and click on the window you want to hide.
4. The next time you start the application it won't show up in the launcher but will still be accessible through the Dash search (and in case of Thunderbird, via the Messaging Menu, too)